# How to merge an audio and a video in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-8, merge, windows-phone

I am making an app in which a person can sing something with a animation playing in background.
I am able to achieve that but if the user wants it to post it on facebook i am unable to merge the audio file that he sang and the video of the animation. I tried a lot but did not succeed in finding any result. is that even possible to merge a audio and a video files in windows phone 8 ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging audio and video is a hard problem and there is no API that will do that easily for you. You should instead look at libraries that aim to solve such problem. Maybe FFMPEG has some functions that can merge audio and video together, but in general, that is not something trivial.